# Can I make Toast text change immediately without waiting the toast end?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, toast

In my app, I construct a pdf viewer  widget for my activity, when I scroll it to previous or next page, I let it make a toast and show the current page number.

The question is, the toast need time to show, when I scroll it fast enough, for example, I scrolled to  page "5" and "06" and scroll to "07" without pause, I have to wait the Toast of "05", "06","07" to show one by one slowly.

**Can I show a specific Toast immediately without waiting?**

```dart
class _PdfoneState extends State<Pdfone> {
 int currentPage1 = 0;

 SharedPreferences? preferences;
 final toast = FToast();

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   toast.init(context);
   initializePreference().whenComplete(() {
     setState(() {});
   });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
       child: PDF(
     enableSwipe: true,
     pageFling: b,
     fitPolicy: FitPolicy.BOTH,
     nightMode: a,
     onPageChanged: (page, total) {
       setState(() {
         currentPage1 = page!;
         this.preferences?.setInt("page1", currentPage1);
       });
       Widget buildToast() => Container(
             padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 14),
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
               color: Colors.white70,
             ),
             child: Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
               children: [
                 Text(
                   "${page! + 1} / $total",
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                 )
               ],
             ),
           );
       void showToast() => toast.showToast(
             child: buildToast(),
             positionedToastBuilder: (context, child) => Positioned(
               child: child,
               top: 32,
               left: 22,
             ),
             fadeDuration: 300,
           );
       showToast();
     },
```

Comment: What is `FToast` in your case?

Comment: I am using  flutterToast package  and to build a custom toast you need to use FToast class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear previous toast and show current one

```dart
// To remove present shwoing toast
fToast.removeCustomToast()
 
// To clear the queue
fToast.removeQueuedCustomToasts();
```

```dart
void showToast(){ 
  toast.removeCustomToast(); // based on your need
  toast.removeQueuedCustomToasts();

  toast.showToast(
             child: buildToast(),
             positionedToastBuilder: (context, child) => Positioned(
               child: child,
               top: 32,
               left: 22,
             ),
             fadeDuration: 300,
           );
    }
```

More about [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast)

Comment: it's work thanks